# Blank page error when using search in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have watched countless videos and tried to implement suggestions from here and edited the code more than I can remember. Could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here? I am trying to get the search to go through the data and filter the cards.

The data loads fine but there are some errors in console
[image: screen before search]

[image: console on page load]

When I try searching, once I type anything letter. The page goes blank

[image]

And console looks like this, Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter') is suggested to be an error if item received is not an array, but the results shows array.

[image: console error].

Here is my code. I am trying to learn so I understand this is very messy and should be in components.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect } from 'react';


function App() {

  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]); 
  // const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState(''); 
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

const handleChange = event => {
  setSearchTerm(event.target.publications);
};

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('https://api.**url.com/api/v1/content/publications?limit=50',{
    headers: {
     'X-AUTH-TOKEN' : '22bc08a8***2995da615c'
    }
  })
    .then(response => { 
      console.log(response.data);
      setData(response.data.data); 
    });
}, []);
  

  return(

    <div>
      
<h1>Publication title goes here </h1>

{/* Search  */}
    
    <div className='App'>
    <input type="text" placeholder='Search' onChange={handleChange}/>
  </div>
{/* Search  end*/}



<div className="px-10 py-10 grid gap-4 md:grid-cols-4">

  {

data.filter((publications) =>{
if (searchTerm == "") {

return publications} 

// else if (data.publications.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())))


{data.publications.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
{
   return publications
}
}}).map(publications => 
  { return (


// card

<div className="user" key={publications.id} className="container mx-auto max-w-4xl">
  
<div class="max-w-sm bg-white border border-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-100 rounded-lg shadow-md dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
    <a href="#">
        <img class="rounded-t-lg" src="/docs/images/blog/image-1.jpg" alt="" />
    </a>
    <div class="p-5">
        <a href="#">
            <h2 class="mb-2 text-2xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900 dark:text-white"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth={1.5} stroke="currentColor" className="w-6 h-6">
  <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M16.5 3.75V16.5L12 14.25 7.5 16.5V3.75m9 0H18A2.25 2.25 0 0120.25 6v12A2.25 2.25 0 0118 20.25H6A2.25 2.25 0 013.75 18V6A2.25 2.25 0 016 3.75h1.5m9 0h-9" />
</svg>
{publications.description}</h2>
        </a>
        <p class="mb-3 font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-400">Author: {publications.author}.</p>
        <a href="#" class="inline-flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium text-center text-white bg-blue-700 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">
            Last Publication
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-4 h-4 ml-2 -mr-1" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.293 3.293a1 1 0 011.414 0l6 6a1 1 0 010 1.414l-6 6a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L14.586 11H3a1 1 0 110-2h11.586l-4.293-4.293a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
        </a>
        
  


        
    </div>
</div>


  </div>


  )


}
  
  )

  }

</div>

</div>

  )


}
  
     

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The errors are showing up in your console, because you have to use `className` instead of `class` in React. You are using `class` in your card component. The other HTML attributes have to be written in camel case, so `fill-rule` becomes `fillRule` and `clip-rule` becomes `clipRule`.

For the issues with your filter, you should have a look at the docs for the [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [String.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) methods. You can't filter an object with the includes method.

Also `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')` is showing up, because `data.publications` IS undefined. Start using Typescript and these errors won't happen again.

Here is an example of how your filter could look like:

```js
data.filter((publication) => {
  // If no search term is set, return true
  if (!searchTerm) {
    return true
  }
  // If either the publication description or the author contain the search term, return true
  if (publication.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) || publication.author.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
    return true
  }
  // If there is a search term and neither the description nor the author contain the search term, return false
  return false
})
```